# Paris : féminin ou masculin?

Tags: genre, noms-propres, géographie

["Paris est sauvée"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Paris%20est%20sauv%C3%A9e%22) : 242,000 results

["Paris est sauvé"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Paris%20est%20sauv%C3%A9%22) : 562,000 results

Paris est-il masculin ou féminin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La remarque n'est pas spécifique à Paris mais se rapporte à tous les noms de villes dont le genre n'est pas marqué dans le nom (« La Rochelle », « Le Bourget »...). Le noms des villes en français sont selon le contexte masculin ou féminin, il n'y a pas de règle, mais, signale Grevisse dans *Le Bon usage*,

> dans la langue parlée du moins, le masculin tende à prévaloir (le neutre, proprement, comme s'il y avait désexualisation générale des noms propres de villes).

Et cette remarque du *Bon usage* corrobore tout à fait le résultat chiffré de ta recherche.

Dans la recherche que tu as faite on constate que la plupart du temps Paris est employé par métonymie

> Paris est sauvé

il s'agit
-  dans tous les premiers exemples d'**un club** sportif (comme le Stade Français, club parisien)
- **du gouvernement** du pays

> Paris est sauvée

il s'agit de
- **la** ville
- **la** bourse
- **la** municipalité

En général quand on parle de Paris dans un contexte historique on emploie le masculin.

> Le Paris du Moyen-âge.

Quand dans son célèbre [discours de l'Hôtel de Ville](http://www.charles-de-gaulle.org/pages/espace-pedagogique/le-point-sur/les-textes-a-connaitre/discours-de-lrsquohotel-de-ville-25-aout-1944.php) De Gaulle, fin littéraire, parle de

> Paris ! Paris outragé ! Paris brisé ! Paris martyrisé ! mais Paris libéré ! libéré par lui-même, libéré par son peuple

(et je donne une citation étendue, car on la trouve trop souvent avec un accord des adjectifs au féminin, comme si le mot « ville » était sous-entendu) et met Paris au masculin.

Comment: Le lien vers le discours de CDG n'est pas plus valable.